# Safe to install production assemblies with gacutil.exe?

Tags: .net, deployment, gacutil

MSDN states that [gacutil.exe is not safe to use for production servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79.aspx). Is there a legitimate reason for this or is Microsoft just practicing a little CYA? Is this warning safe to ignore? Or should I finally learn how to use Microsoft Windows Installer 2.0?

MSDN's exact wording:

> Gacutil.exe is only for development purposes and should not be used to install production assemblies into the global assembly cache.

Comment: "not safe"? Where does that wording appear?

Comment: Sorry. I guess I was inferring a little bit. It said it is only for development purposes. Added the MSDN language.

Comment: Ok, better. Just wanted to verify that's what it said, and not confuse any future readers. :)

Comment: The warning is probably there because gacutil.exe runs with Administrator privileges and has the possibility of unintentionally overwriting or deleting other similarly named assemblies from the global cache if used improperly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Items in the global assembly cache are shared across programs.

When you use Gacutil to add an assembly to the cache, there will be no reference counting of items that depend on it.  Therefore, it is possible that when you use GacUtil /U to remove your library from the cache, you will have broken other programs that depend on it.

In contrast, Windows Installer 2.0 keeps a count and will only remove libraries from the assembly cache when no other program requires it.

Comment: This answer technically answered my question better than Hans' (even though Hans read into the question and was helpful that way). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

That's because gacutil.exe won't be available on the target machine.  It is part of the Windows SDK, the .NET 4.0 version of it is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools.  You have it on your machine because you installed Visual Studio.

You simply do it with an installer.  In a Setup project, right-click the File System pane, Add Special Folder and pick "Global Assembly Cache Folder".  And put the DLL in there.

Comment: Another good point.  I hadn't thought about that, but it does get installed with VS, doesn't it?

Comment: I know it wasnt on the production machine, but since the shell extension is giving me trouble, I thought I could just copy it over.

Comment: The shell extension is no longer available in .NET 4.  Also beware that the GAC has moved from c:\windows\assembly to c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly.

Comment: Geez. The Setup project was ridiculously easy to use. I should not be afraid to try new things :) Thanks.